# What's the appropriate Hungarian Notation prefix for a PHP stdClass?

Tags: php, naming-conventions, hungarian-notation

If there is one, that is.

(Such as nInteger, chChar, cCount or rgArray.)

Comment: You may want to give this a read: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/102689/what-is-the-benefit-of-not-using-hungarian-notation

Comment: I might be entirely wrong (so let me phrase this as a question); I thought use of Hungarian Notation was discouraged with OOP?

Comment: Have you considered using a decent IDE and dumping Hungarian notation entirely? Very few programmers these days will argue that using Hungarian notation to define types is a good idea. **For example, the most upvoted answer to this question:**
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202107/good-examples-of-hungarian-notation/202135#202135

Comment: I should clarify that I wouldn't do this on a "personal" project, but I'm jumping into someone else's project where Hungarian Notation is the norm.

Comment: How about `$oFoo = new stdclass;`?