# Parse a file name from char * variable

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have a value in character pointer variable and the value is changed dynamically.

for e.g

```
one case:
   char *ptr = sometext || abc.txt;

second case:
   char *ptr = abc.txt || sometext;
```

I need only file name in another variable.
str = abc.txt

currently I am using the code:

```
CString str;
char* lpszToToken = stLine.GetBuffer(stLine.GetLength());
char* lpszToken = strtok(lpszToToken, "|");
while(lpszToken != NULL)
{
   lpszToken = strtok(NULL, "|");
   str = lpszToken;
}
```

but it working in only first case:
I need a genric code to run in both case
Any idea?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

My C is rusty, but why not something like:

```
char* fname = strtok( fileNames, "|");
while (fname != NULL) {
    // do something with the file here..
    processFile( fname);             
    fname = strtok( NULL, "|");         // next.
}
```

Also, Hungarian notation is a horrible way to program. It effectively conceals & obfuscates most meaning, rendering clear and simple problems opaque & ugly. See how readable my example is, compared with the gack you supplied?

Your instructor (and Petzold) were very unfortunately mistaken to be teaching this to you. I suggest writing "literate" code instead.

See:

- [Good Examples of Hungarian Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202107/good-examples-of-hungarian-notation)
- http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html

Comment: @sasha.sochka Please provide a rationale/link for this kind of general statements.

Comment: If my opinion was somewhere counted I would vote that `strtok` is the worst designed function for ever (in C)

Comment: I agree with Sasha. Hidden global state (worse than using global variables, since it is opaque), unclear API design & security issues. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999418/why-is-strtok-considered-unsafe  But hey, I used it when I was a newbie too.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have CString available you can use CString::Find or CString::Tokenize