# C# Exclude Array Object

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a slight problem with this code:

```
string[] sWords = {"Word 1", "Word2"}
foreach (string sWord in sWords)
{
  Console.WriteLine(sWord);
}
```

This works fine if I want every object to print.

I was wondering if I could exclude the first item in the array? 
So it would only output "Word 2". I know the obvious solution is not to include the first item but in this case I can't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop instead:

```
string[] sWords = {"Word 1", "Word2"};
var len = sWords.Length;

for (int i = 1; i < len; i++)
{
  Console.WriteLine(sWords[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Using LINQ to Objects, you can just use [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx):

```
foreach (string word in words.Skip(1))
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Using LINQ in .Net 3.5 and up:

```
string[] words = {"Word 1", "Word2"}
foreach (string word in words.Skip(1))
{  
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

Note that you must have a `using System.Linq;` statement at the top of your file, as [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) is an extension method.

An alternative option is to use a regular for loop:

```
for( int x = 1; x < words.Length; ++x )
    Console.WriteLine(words[x]);
```

I also *strongly* discourage the use of Hungarian-like prefixes in variable names in .Net.

Comment: Ok, thanks, why would you advice not to use these variable names?

Comment: @Bali: They add no value (the type of the variable indicates that it's a string array) and just make it harder to read the code.

Comment: @Bali C: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111933/why-shouldnt-i-use-hungarian-notation

Comment: Because common style guidelines for C# encourage you not to use Hungarian notation. Hungarian notation also encodes sometimes unnecessary type information in the names, which can make refactoring the code more difficult (as you'd have to change the names if you change the type).

Answer (score 3):

You could do

```
string[] sWords = {"Word 1", "Word2"};

 for(int i=1; i<sWords.Length; i++) 
 {   
   Console.WriteLine(sWord[i]); 
 }
```