# Verify a php variable if there is a javascript code

Tags: php, javascript

I have some variables in PHP (strings) and I vould like to check if inside of those strings I have some javascript code. If so, I would like to make this code inactive and be displayed as string on the website, not to be executed as javascript code.

This will be a kind of security method.

Is there a method to do it in php? If you could give me an example, it's even better.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be using `htmlspecialchars()` for any content you output into HTML.  It escapes any HTML entities so that they are not taken literally.  For example, `<` becomes `&lt;`.  This also solves your problem.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: Thank you very much @Brad. The htmlspecialchars will transform some special characters like 
    & (ampersand) becomes &amp;
    " (double quote) becomes &quot;
    ' (single quote) becomes &#039;
    < (less than) becomes &lt;
    > (greater than) becomes &gt;
in html. With that, the javascript execution will be avoid, right?

Comment: @Ana, That is correct, unless you were to wrap that output in `<script>` tags.  The concept is that without `<script>` tags, the JavaScript can't execute.  It just appears as text on the page.  There is no way for someone to insert `<script>` tags, as they would turn out to be `&lt;script&gt;`.

Comment: Great, thank you very much. I will take a couple of minutes to checki if this solution is properly adapted to my code and I will let you know as soon as possible.

Comment: I am here again. The solution is perfectly adapted to my needs. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Brad's answer, consider reading the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111933/why-shouldnt-i-use-hungarian-notation) for a short summary and then the therein mentioned [article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html) afterwards.

This can help you to easily avoid outputting unsafe strings by accident.

Comment: Of course, but the link is much appreciated.  Not sure how I've missed this over the years...