# Define an object with a name constructed using a dynamic value

Tags: c#, variables, for-loop

Okay, I have this piece of code:

```
int arrPanelsRequired = 4;
string airport;
int arrPanelsMade = 0;
for (; arrPanelsMade <= arrPanelsRequired; arrPanelsMade++)
{
    Panel arrPanelXXX = new Panel();
```

and I need to replace the `XXX` with the value of `arrPanelsMade`. I found several ways to name an object after a variable's value, however, I wasn't able to apply any of them here :(

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Sounds like you're actually looking for a list or array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it would be a good idea in general, let alone in C#. I can see many `arr` prefixes, which leads me to the use of an array. I think you might be looking for something like this:

```
int arrPanelsRequired = 4;
Panel[] panels = new Panel[arrPanelsRequired];
for (int arrPanelsMade = 0; arrPanelsMade < arrPanelsRequired; arrPanelsMade++)
{
    panels[arrPanelsMade] = new Panel();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is bad practice. It passes in weakly-typed languages, but in strongly-typed languages such as C#, variables need to be explicitly declared. This helps the compiler to catch errors that can be caused by typos or general development mistakes. For example, if you have a variable `arrPanel089`, how can you/the compiler know if it has been declared? Strong typing can seem like a constraint when coming from weakly-typed languages, but it is really a great tool that saves you a ton of headache as the developer.

If you want to create a set of panels, store them in an array/list/etc and access them by their index. If you want to give them a key, store them in a dictionary which allows you to access values by key instead.

Comment: It's not only that they _shouldn't_ be, it's that they _need_ to be.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the panels to a List or array, and access them later by index:

```
arrPanel = new Panel[arrPanelsRequired];
for( int idx = 0 ; idx < arrPanelsRequired ; idx++)
    arrPanel[idx] = new Panel();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of things going on here that raise red flags.  I'll digress from your question just a bit, because I think you're probably going down the wrong road in a couple of respects.

1. Drop the "arr" prefix, and just call your variables what they are — don't try to emulate [Hungarian Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111933/why-shouldnt-i-use-hungarian-notation) unless you've got good reason to do so.
2. Consider using a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop if you're not going to perform your initialization in the loop header.
3. Now on to your question.  No, the language doesn't work like that.  Use a `List<Panel>` class instead.  That will allow you to add more panels dynamically without having to predefine how many you want, such as in an array.