# Settings in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, configuration, settings

I have a question on eclipse settings.

I want to declare some variables having special characters in it i.e. `m_memberVar` etc and want to generate the getter and setter by eliminating the special character and in standard format i.e. for above variable, the getter and setter method will be

```
public void setMemberVar(DataType dt) {}
```

and `public ReturnType getMemberVar() {}`

But the default settings in eclipse does not generate above methods instead generates `getM_memberVar()` and `setM_memberVar().`

Is it possible to settings accordingly so that above requirement can be fulfilled?
Can I prepare some xml file with all editor related settings I require in my project and import it in eclipse?

Thanks in advance and waiting for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `m_` or `p_` as prefixes. Eclipse shows such variables in different colors so the difference is obvious. And it really isn't a good practice to use this prefixes it just clutters your code in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I went through some code in google and in other codebase and found that this is common practice to use m_ as prefix for member variables.

Comment: @javadeveloper maybe it was 10 years ago and now this is legacy code. When you start a new project you should stick to more modern style of coding.

Comment: @javadeveloper see [What are the benefits of prefixing function parameter names with p*?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/161283/what-are-the-benefits-of-prefixing-function-parameter-names-with-p) and [Why shouldn't I use “Hungarian Notation”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111933/why-shouldnt-i-use-hungarian-notation) for more opinions on that.