# How To Pass Different Objects to same Function in C#

Tags: c#, function, object

I have 10 different classes, but below are two for the purpose of this question :

```
public class Car
{
    public int CarId {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class Lorry
{
    public int LorryId {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Now I have a function like

```
public static object MyFunction(object oObject, string sJson)
{
    //do something with the object like below 
    List<oObject> oTempObject= new List<oObject>();
    oTempObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<oObject>>(sJson);
    return oTempObject;
}
```

What I'm wanting to do is pass the object I create like (oCar) below to the function.

```
Car oCar = new Car();
```

My question is how can I pass a object of a different type to the same function ?

Comment: You should read this as well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111933/why-shouldnt-i-use-hungarian-notation

Comment: Everywhere you're using `oObject` in that function, you're using it like a type. Shouldn't this just be a generic method with a type argument instead of `oObject`?

Comment: Why dont you use Generic
Something like `public static object MyFunction<T>(T oObject, string sJson)`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I think he's just adding that to illustrate his intentions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using generic methods will solve the trick:

```
public static List<T> MyFunction<T>(string sJson)
{
    //do something with the object like below 
    return (List<T>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(sJson);
}
```

Usage:

```
List<Car> cars = MyFunction<Car>(sJson);
```

or

```
List<Lorry> cars = MyFunction<Lorry>(sJson);
```

Update (thanks to Matthew for noticing the type behind the method name), 
btw: this is not needed when a parameter is type T.

Comment: I agree 100%, although I would suggest adding the usage.  Chances are he's not familiar with <T>.

Comment: Many thanks, much appreciated.  This is what I wanted.  How do you guys know so much.

Comment: We all know a little, together we know much ;-)

Comment: You would have to specify the type when calling `MyFunction` as it cannot be inferred through it's usage.  `var cars = MyFunction<Car>(json);`