# Generate prefixes for variable/pointer names visual studio 2013 c++

Tags: c++, macros, visual-studio-2013, prefix

I was in class and they were emphasising on the importance of using prefixes to make your code more readable.
As a lazy programmer, I've learnt that there's often a way to macro or automate something to reduce the typing needed. I'm a big fan of hotkeys etc.
Now this got me to wonder , is it possible to create something like a macro (VS 2013 - macro's are deleted from the program) that would write prefixes in declarations for you?

I imagine just being able to write a list like this :

TextBox - txt

BitMap - bmp

Member variable - m_

...

And then next time you'd write a declaration, it would automaticly put in the prefix after you press the space.

Resharper in c# has something similar, where they would basicly update intelisense to do this, so I imagine c++ having something like this aswell? 
If not, what langauge should I look into to create this type of code?
Intensive googling unfortunately did not yield the answer.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111933/why-shouldnt-i-use-hungarian-notation and be sure to read the linked article (http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html). Thou shall not use hungarian notation for indicating type.

Comment: Nothing has done more to destroy readability than prefixes. Do the lazy thing and avoid them.

Comment: @molbdnilo Elaborate?