# C# SerialPort System.ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, exception, port

I created a communication module, one of the modules responsibilities is to detect  ports which send a certain signature, I achieve that by setting a recognizer delegate to be called from OnDataRecive for all the port, when I wait a while. after that I remove the recognizer delegate from all the ports, the irrelevant ports are closed and disposed, the relevant ports receive a replacement delegate to be called on data received.

```
public override bool fSearchPortsForSilDevices(dPortChangedHandler p_hPortAdded, dPortChangedHandler p_hPortRemoved, cSilPort.dDataReceivedHandler p_hSilDevRecognaizer){
        string[]        l_strPortNames  = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        cSilUARTport    l_oUART_Port    = null;
        bool            l_isSilDevFound = false;
        try
        {

            foreach (cSilUARTport l_oPort in m_oPortsDictionary.Values)
            {
                l_oPort.fClose();
            }

            m_oPortsDictionary.Clear();//AmitTODO: figure out if clear also destroy the instances, so the serial ports will be closed.

            foreach (var l_strPortName in l_strPortNames)
            {
                l_oUART_Port = new cSilUARTport(l_strPortName);
                m_oPortsDictionary.Add(l_strPortName, l_oUART_Port);
                l_oUART_Port.DataReceived = p_hSilDevRecognaizer;
            }

            Thread.Sleep(100);//Amit: we must wait and allow each port to send a realtime message.

            foreach (var l_strPortName in l_strPortNames)//Amit: close all none Sil related ports and remove them from the dictionary.
            {
                if (m_oPortsDictionary.TryGetValue(l_strPortName, out l_oUART_Port))
                {

                    if (!l_oUART_Port.SilDev)
                    {
                        m_oPortsDictionary.Remove(l_strPortName);
                        p_hPortRemoved(l_oUART_Port);
                        l_oUART_Port.fClose();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        p_hPortAdded(l_oUART_Port);//AmitTODO: will detecte which device is it, and will set a a reading function for it.
                        l_isSilDevFound = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
        }

        return l_isSilDevFound;
    }
```

In case of communication dropdown I call the same function again.

After testing it: plugging and unplugging USB I receive:
ObjectDisposedException: Safe handle has been closed

I managed to catch the exception and print the stack trace but there is no trace back to my code( [image: Stack Trace])

SilUARTPort:

```
public class cSilUARTport : cSilPort
{
    #region Members
    private SerialPort  m_oSerPort  = null;
    private bool        m_isSilDev  = false;
    #endregion
    #region CTOR/DTOR
    private cSilUARTport() { }
    public cSilUARTport(string p_strPortName){
        try{
            m_strPortType = "UART";
            m_oSerPort = new SerialPort(p_strPortName);
            if (m_oSerPort != null && m_oSerPort.IsOpen == false) 
                fOpen();
        }
        catch
        {}
    }
    ~cSilUARTport(){
        try{
            if (m_oSerPort.IsOpen == true) fClose();
        }
        catch
        { }
    }
    #endregion
    #region Accessories
    public bool SilDev
    {
        get { return m_isSilDev; }
        set { m_isSilDev = value; }
    }
    public string PortName
    {
        get { return m_oSerPort.PortName; }
        set { m_oSerPort.PortName = value; }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Methods
    public override void fOpen()
    {
        try
        {
            m_oSerPort.BaudRate     = cSilConstants.Com.UARTport.c_iBaudRate;
            m_oSerPort.DataBits     = 8;
            m_oSerPort.StopBits     = StopBits.One;
            m_oSerPort.Parity       = Parity.None;
            m_oSerPort.Handshake    = Handshake.None;
            m_oSerPort.ReadTimeout  = cSilConstants.Com.UARTport.c_iTimeOut;
            m_oSerPort.WriteTimeout = cSilConstants.Com.UARTport.c_iTimeOut;
            m_oSerPort.DataReceived += fDataReceived;
            m_oSerPort.ReadTimeout  = 100;
            m_oSerPort.WriteTimeout = 100;
            m_oSerPort.Open();
        }
        catch
        {}
    }

    public override void fClose(){
        try{
            m_oSerPort.Close();
            m_oSerPort.Dispose();
        }
        catch
        {}
    }
    public override void fWrite(byte[] p_bData){
        m_oSerPort.Write(p_bData, 0, p_bData.Count());
    }
    #endregion
    #region Handlers
    private void fDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e){
        try{
            byte[] l_Data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(m_oSerPort.ReadExisting());
            if (m_hDataReceived(l_Data) == 1) m_isSilDev = true;
        }
        catch
        {}
    }
    #endregion
    #region Assist Functions
    public override bool Equals(object obj){
        var other = obj as cSilPort;
        if (other == null) return false;
        return Equals(other);
    }
    public override bool Equals(cSilPort obj){
        var other = obj as cSilUARTport;
        return (m_oSerPort.PortName == other.m_oSerPort.PortName);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see where you ever open the port, or check if its open before you close it. Also, what is `cSilUARTport`?

Comment: [Very much (sarcasm?) related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/111933/1997232).

Comment: @RonBeyer Hi I updated the post, now its containing SilUARTport, there you can see where I open the  port how I close it and the class SilUARTport.
Hope it make a difference.