# MVC varing relations between tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC and am used to using Forms. My question is suppose I have basic models setup for four tables with the following fields;

```
    Branch
    ------
    Branch_Nu
    Branch_Address

    Orders
   -----
    Order_Nu
    Branch_Nu
    Product_Nu
    Customer_Nu
    totcost

    Products
    ---------
    Product_Nu
    Product
    Price

    Customer
    ----------
    Customer_Nu
    Name
    Address
    City
    St
    Zip
```

I'm interested in the following scenarios,

```
I want to see all orders for a branch; 
Branch->orders

I want to see all orders for a customer from a particular branch;
Branch->orders->products
         |-->customer

I want to see all orders for a customer regardless of branch they
purchased from; 
customer->orders->branch

I want to see all branches that sold a particular product;
products->orders->Branch

I want to see which customers bought a particular product;
products->orders->customer
```

Question is can I use different controllers for the different scenarios using the same basic models that is submitted to different controller methods, or do I need different models for the different scenarios which is then submitted to different controller methods?

If I were using forms I would just have a different select statements and forms for each scenario, in MVC?

Answer (score 0):

> Question is can I use different controllers for the different scenarios using the same basic models

Yes

> do I need different models for the different scenarios which is then submitted to different controller methods

You don't need them, but generally speaking using a model for a different logical function tends (not always) to break the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

In your instance it appears you are viewing the same data by different views (not logic).  An order is an order, for viewing purposes anywhere on your site, generally I use the same model.  *Placing* an order (different logic function) I would most likely have a new model.

Considering you are viewing the same data this is a classic example of the best use of [MVC Templates](https://exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-display-and-editor-templates/).

> If I were using forms I would just have a different select statements and forms for each scenario, in MVC?

I would probably design it like:

```
I want to see all orders for a branch; 
Branch->orders
public class BranchController() { public ActionResult Orders() {}}

I want to see all orders for a customer from a particular branch;
Branch->orders->products
         |-->customer
public class BranchController() 
{ 
   public ActionResult Orders() {}
   public ActionResult CustomerOrders() {}
   public ActionResult ProductOrders() {}
}

// ETC
```

A model example:

```
public class OrderVM
{
  //I would get rid of hungarian notation
  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111933/why-shouldnt-i-use-hungarian-notation
  public int OrderId { get; set; }
  public int BranchId { get; set; }
  public int ProductId { get; set; }
  public int CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

Then store *how* the html is rendered in `/views/shared/templates/display/OrderVM.cshtml` so it can be used throughout the application, allowing overrides per controller/area as well.

Answer (score 0):

your entity framework models represent the relationships between your classes. In a code first approach, your models will dictate the design of your database. Take the following three classes for example:

```
public class Cat 
{
  [Key]
  public int Id {get; set;} 

  public string Name {get; set;}

  //Foreign key to animalgroup table
  public int AnimalGroupId {get; set;}

  //navigation property to AnimalGroup
  //allows you to do myCat.AnimalGroup outside of this class to retrieve
  //the associated animal group
  public virtual AnimalGroup AnimalGroup {get; set;}
}

public class Dog
{ 
  [Key]
  public int Id {get; set;}

  public string Name {get; set;}

  public bool IsFluffy {get; set;}

  //Foreign key to animalgroup table
  public int AnimalGroupId {get; set;}

  //navigation property to AnimalGroup
  //allows you to do myDog.AnimalGroup outside of this class to retrieve
  //the associated animal group
  public virtual AnimalGroup AnimalGroup {get; set;}
}

public class AnimalGroup
{
  [Key]
  public int Id {get; set;}

  public string Name {get; set;}     

  public virtual ICollection<Cat> Cats {get; set;}

  public virtual ICollection<Dog> Dogs {get; set;
}
```

this represents two one-to-many relationships. A `AnimalGroup` can contain multiple Cats and an `AnimalGroup` can contain many Dogs. You can write queries to do CRUD operations. A very simplistic example is the following:

```
//create and save an animal group
AnimalGroup group = new AnimalGroup();
group.Name = "my animal group";
_dbContext.AnimalGroups.Add(group);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();

//create and save a cat associated with the animal group
Cat myCat = new Cat();
cat.Name = "kitty";
cat.AnimalGroupId = group.Id;
_dbContext.Cats.Add(myCat);

_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```