# Hungarian Notation in VS17

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, code-formatting, prefix

For some reason the company I work for enforces Hungarian Notation. I know this is not a correct convention and increases the difficulty for reading the code. However this still enforce it. Since i cannot find anything i ask you this question.

Example of the Hungarian Notation:

```
string   sName   = "Hans";
integer  iAge    = 57;
Boolean  bAdult  = true;
DateTime dtBirth = new DateTime(15,5,1984);
Float    fBudger = 4500,20;
```

**Is it possible to enforce this using VS17 .editorconfig?**

Or am I able to enforce this by using another method?

I searched for this in Microsofts documentation of .editorconfig and i searched for anything related to this on stack overflow.

I also checked the options>Text Editor but did not find anything related there either.

PS: Possibly this is also fitting as a Superuser question. However this is written in `XML`

Comment: Better convince your company to [not use hungarian notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111933/why-shouldnt-i-use-hungarian-notation) ... vUsing adjHungarian nnotation vmakes nreading ncode adjdifficult.

Comment: yea, I know... and it seems very unnecessary. thanks though, now I know how this is called.

Comment: that's so 1990 :) Jokes apart. Maybe StyleCop could help you with that or the second thing i can think of is to write your own Analyzer and Code Fix https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/How-To-Write-a-C%23-Analyzer-and-Code-Fix

Comment: An abandoned approach won't have its place in modern tooling, so you probably should stop searching. Enforcing such is also a waste of energy like others commented.