# Do you have any personal visual clue in your code for other user and not the compiler?

Tags: php, coding-style

i use certain suffix in my variable name, a combination of an underscore and a property. such as :

```
$variable_html = variable that will be parse in html code.

$variable_str = string variable

$variable_int = integer variable

$variable_flo = float variable.
```

Do you have other visual clues? Maybe something you write for variable, function name, class strucure, or other stuff that helps others to read and not only for compiler ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do people use the Hungarian Naming Conventions in the real world?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428/do-people-use-the-hungarian-naming-conventions-in-the-real-world)

Comment: Just a note; PHP is an interpreted language, there is no compiler here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're describing Hungarian Notation: [Do people use the Hungarian Naming Conventions in the real world?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428/do-people-use-the-hungarian-naming-conventions-in-the-real-world)

There's lots of discussion on Stack Overflow about people's feelings on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

It nearly is Hungarian Notation, but when you use Hungarian Notation it is more common to use a prefix instead of a suffix.